# Jenkins : add external folder zip at deployement time

Tags: jenkins

We use Jenkins with build Parameters plugin and Publish over ssh plugin.

I need to zip a folder from the network and  add it to the ressources deployed.

The transfert Panel option seems to be the good place where  to do that, in the source files combo it is possible to specify a command to exec. But i can't figure how the zipped folder should be included in the sources to deploy...

Any hints ?

Comment: please add a screenshot if you think it might help clarify.

Comment: I'm new to jenkins, i have understood the build process can be extended with plugins. So I had the "Files Operations" plugni, which copy the folder i need from network into the worspace directory ogf the jenkins job. Unfortunately the zip operation does not work. So i had added a windows managed batch script opération which zip the folder before moving.